# How to use flexmark-java modify the url of the picture in the markdown file?

Tags: java, kotlin, markdown, commonmark

I follow [CustomLinkResolverSample.java](https://github.com/vsch/flexmark-java/blob/master/flexmark-java-samples/src/com/vladsch/flexmark/java/samples/CustomLinkResolverSample.java) example and [Render AST as Markdown with Formatting Options](https://github.com/vsch/flexmark-java/wiki/Usage#render-ast-as-markdown-with-formatting-options) to implement custom parsing link, but not working.

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val str = "![cover](https://www.google.com)"
    val options = PegdownOptionsAdapter.flexmarkOptions(
        Extensions.ALL
    )
    val parser = Parser.builder(options).build()
    val document = parser.parse(str)
    val formatOptions = MutableDataSet()
        .set(Parser.EXTENSIONS, Parser.EXTENSIONS.get(options))
        .set(
            Parser.EXTENSIONS,
            Collections.singletonList(SageFormatterExtension.create()) as Collection<Extension>
        )
    val render = Formatter.builder(formatOptions).build()
    val result = render.render(document)
    println(result)
}
```

`SageFormatterExtension`

```kotlin
class SageFormatterExtension: FormatterExtension {
    override fun rendererOptions(options: MutableDataHolder?) {
    }

    override fun extend(formatterBuilder: Formatter.Builder) {
        formatterBuilder.linkResolverFactory(DocxLinkResolver.Factory)
    }

    companion object {
        fun create(): SageFormatterExtension {
            return SageFormatterExtension()
        }
    }
}
```

`DocxLinkResolver`

```kotlin
class DocxLinkResolver(val context: LinkResolverBasicContext) : LinkResolver {

    override fun resolveLink(node: Node, context: LinkResolverBasicContext, link: ResolvedLink): ResolvedLink {
        println("resolveLink")
        return link
    }

    object Factory : LinkResolverFactory {
        override fun apply(context: LinkResolverBasicContext): LinkResolver {
            return DocxLinkResolver(context)
        }

        override fun getAfterDependents(): MutableSet<Class<*>>? {
            return null
        }

        override fun getBeforeDependents(): MutableSet<Class<*>>? {
            return null
        }

        override fun affectsGlobalScope(): Boolean {
            return false
        }

    }

}
```

`println("resolveLink")` did not run, indicating that the extension was not loaded.

What am I missing? Or is there any other solution?